# My C program is recursing infinitely and I cannot figure out why

Tags: c, recursion

This program is supposed to take a name from a user and output it backwards. Our professor said we had to use recursion and I am struggling with getting to not recurse infinitely. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reversedWord(char input[],int size)
{   int count;
    int count2;
    if(count==0) {
        count2=size;
    }
    count2=count2-1;
    char store;
    store=input[count2];
    input[count2]=input[count];
    input[count]=store;
    count=count+1;
    if(count>size)
    {
        return;
    }
    return reversedWord(input,size);
}

int main()
{
    char input[100];
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s",input);
    int size=strlen(input);
    reversedWord(input,size);
    printf("\n Your name backwards: %s \n",input);
}
```

Comment: `int count;
    int count2;
    if(count == 0)` ... Here `count` holds garbage value!

Comment: You're returning from a `void` function, instead you should just be printing the reverse word/string in that function. The first time you call that function from the main, you need to check within the function if the `input[]` is `\0`. If not, then move the array ahead by 1 and recursively call the `reversedWord()` function

Comment: A decent way to debug such type of bugs is to print the variables responsible for the change of control. Try printing the variables `count` and `size` to magically see where its going wrong. GL.

Comment: count and count2 are local variables, you used them before initialize.

Comment: I doubt that code compiles.

Comment: Start by turning on compiler warning, and fixing them. Use `-Wall -Wextra` for *gcc* and *clang* compilers.

Comment: Try to find such bugs at least 2 days before posting questions!

Answer (score 0):

Since you use counters inside your recursive function they should be `static`, I suggest reading documentation about what `static` does in the C language if it is new to you.

Below is your code with working recursion, but your algorithm for word reversion contains an error. I believe you can solve it yourself with a bit of thought, so I will just give a hint - it reverses the word, but then reverses it back right again.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void reversedWord(char input[],int size)
{   
    static int count = 0;
    static int count2;
    if(count==0) {
        count2=size;
    }
    count2=count2-1;
    char store;
    store=input[count2];
    input[count2]=input[count];
    input[count]=store;
    count=count+1;
    if(count>size)
    {
        return;
    }

    reversedWord(input,size);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char input[100];
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s",input);
    int size=strlen(input);
    reversedWord(input,size);
    printf("\n Your name backwards: %s \n",input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First in the above code, you need to initialize your variables count and count2.

The statements int count; means that you are declaring the variable count of integer type. But it doesn't hold any value.

for this example to have the recursion working, you need to pass 3 parameters(input string, start_index,end_index) at each call to the function.

Here's the modified code to have this working

```
void reversedWord(char input[],int start,int end)
{
    end=end-1;
    char store;
    store=input[end];
    input[end]=input[start];
    input[start]=store;
    start=start+1;
    if(start>=end)
    {
        return;
    }
    return reversedWord(input,start,end);
}

int main()
{
    char input[100];
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s",input);
    int size=strlen(input);
    reversedWord(input,0,size);
    printf("\n Your name backwards: %s \n",input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think even if you assign zero to count and count2 ,this will not work because you are calling the function recursively.

So every time you call reversedWord(input,size) the values are again initialized;

```
> void reversedWord(char input[],int size) {   int count; //initialized
> for every recursive call
>     int count2; //initialized for every recursive call
>     if(count==0) {
>         count2=size;
>     }
>     count2=count2-1;
>     char store;
>     store=input[count2];
>     input[count2]=input[count];
>     input[count]=store;
>     count=count+1;
>     if(count>size)
>     {
>         return;
>     }
>     return reversedWord(input,size); }
```

A better solution would be to declare these two variables count and count2 as static.
 **static int count,count2 ;**
by default the static variable are assigned as 0 and they share a common memory,so no new space is assigned to them and the new values get reflected on the same variable(initialized just once)